# Broadcom wireless disabled after sleep on HP Pavillion

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I've dropped a Ubuntu 14.04 onto a new HP Pavilion laptop. After installing the bcmwl-kernel-source package, the Wi-Fi appears to work, however after putting the laptop to sleep (via closing the lid) and waking it, the Network-Manager shows the Wi-Fi as "disabled via hardware switch", even though the laptop doesn't have a hardware switch.
rfkill also shows the status as "Hard Blocked".

lspci shows the card as a Broadcom Corporation BCM43142.

Any suggestions?